# How to do more space with vertical scroll bar?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do more space in my panel. So how I can do more space with scrollbar? But without(AutoScroll because it doesn't work).

So how I can do this?

Comment: Autoscroll does work.Set the panel's autoscroll property to true and add multiple controls to it, the scroll bar automatically appears.You can also set the scroll bar to be always visible.

Comment: Guessing somewhat at the real question: set the AutoScrollMinSize to, say, (0,1000).  You now get a scrollbar that works at design-time as well, giving you room to drop controls.  Back to (0,0) when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

**1 --> go to panel property**

**2 -->set autoscroll property to true**

[image]